# Ethereum Lottery

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

This website claims it's using BTCRelay http://ethereumlottery.io/

and I checked their source code:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x40658db197bddea6a51cb576fe975ca488ab3693#readContract

their BTCRelay contract resides at:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x41f274c0023f83391de4e0733c609df5a124c3d4

but as you see this is not verified or so.. How can we trust this?

To my understanding it would be better if there was a SINGLE btcrelay contract that's address can be looked up from http://btcrelay.org/ and then I can trust.

I really want ETH world to go beyond investing to applications like this but the level of trust does not really convince me with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> their BTCRelay contract resides at:
>   https://etherscan.io/address/0x41f274c0023f83391de4e0733c609df5a124c3d4
>   but as you see this is not verified or so.. How can we trust this?

According to http://btcrelay.surge.sh/mainnetStatus.html, 0x41f274c0023f83391de4e0733c609df5a124c3d4 is the official address of the contract on mainnet.

This website, btcrelay.surge.sh, looks to be legit - as it is linked to from the [official github repo](https://github.com/ethereum/btcrelay/tree/master#btc-relay-contract-address-and-abi) as a source of truth for determining the mainnet address.

Steps to verify the bytecode are also listed on the [btc relay website](http://btcrelay.surge.sh/mainnetStatus.html).

Comment: Oh great, that makes sense. I somehow mixed the addresses then. :) I also wrote http but let's emphasize making sure checking the website on https is essential!

Comment: Yes =). I totally, agree with the sentiments expressed in your question; your scepticism, your drive to verify the code, your desire to reuse what is already available and proven to work and your enthusiasm for more real-world, useful applications to be built on Ethereum.